# Can't find the template admin/base_site.html in Django 1.8.3

Tags: django

I am looking for the template **admin/base_site.html** , but I can't find it anywhere. This folder is empty

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

no admin folder here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/template
```

or here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/templatetags
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs say, it's in the contrib/admin app inside Django. So, presumably:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also find where the file is using the Python shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib import admin
>>> admin.__path__[0] + "/templates/admin/base_site.html"
```

Since django was not installed in the other directories described in the question/answer on my computer.